# Pushing coordinates to path array

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I am trying to push several coordinates to an array and then draw a polygon with those points. My code looks like

```
             var path = [];
             var polyLatLng1 = new google.maps.LatLng(8.65, 12.74);
             path.push(polyLatLng1);
             var polyLatLng2 = new google.maps.LatLng(23.8, 34.87);
             path.push(polyLatLng2);
             var polyLatLng3 = new google.maps.LatLng(4.16, 21.04);
             path.push(polyLatLng3);
             polygon = new google.maps.Polygon({
                paths: path,
                fillColor: '#1E90FF',
                strokeWeight: 0,
                fillOpacity: 0.45,
              });
```

But this does not draw a polygon at all. Thanks for your help!

Comment: How are you adding it to the map?

Comment: Oh wow I actually forgot to setMap... If you want to you can make an answer like your comment, so this question doesn't appear as unanswered anymore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the polygon to your map:

```
polygon = new google.maps.Polygon({
    paths: path,
    fillColor: '#1E90FF',
    strokeWeight: 0,
    fillOpacity: 0.45,
    map: map
 });
```

[working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wt158sea/)

working code snippet:

```js
function initialize() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), {
    zoom: 2,
    center: {
      lat: -28,
      lng: 137.883
    }
  });

  var path = [];
  var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();

  var polyLatLng1 = new google.maps.LatLng(8.65, 12.74);
  path.push(polyLatLng1);
  bounds.extend(polyLatLng1);
  var polyLatLng2 = new google.maps.LatLng(23.8, 34.87);
  path.push(polyLatLng2);
  bounds.extend(polyLatLng2);
  var polyLatLng3 = new google.maps.LatLng(4.16, 21.04);
  path.push(polyLatLng3);
  bounds.extend(polyLatLng3);
  polygon = new google.maps.Polygon({
    paths: path,
    fillColor: '#1E90FF',
    strokeWeight: 0,
    fillOpacity: 0.45,
    map: map
  });
  map.fitBounds(bounds);

}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

```css
html,
body,
#map-canvas {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<div id="map-canvas"></div>
```